# Dynamically Change The Action Form Attr

Tags: javascript, forms

I have something to ask...

1. How to dynamically change the action for the form tag from username & password value that we get.. example when the value is admin, the action form will dedicated to index_admin.html.

Or

2. How to change the value of "#batas" based on username & password.. in case, on the different file.

Here's the `index.html` markup:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About Us</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="product.html">Product</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="masuk.html" id="batas">Masuk</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

and here is the login page's code

```
<form action="" id="form_id" method="post" name="myForm">
                <script>
                    document.get
                </script>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="username">Username</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Masukkan username" ></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="password">Password</label></td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Masukkan password" ></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="login" id="submit" onclick="validate()"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
```

Thank you very much for someone who asnwer this

Comment: This should be a server side script part, since you have a form post.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is, add a listener for `submit` action to your form. Once it is triggered, you need to prevent the default behavior of the form submit action and do some calculations to change the `action` attribute dynamically based on some conditions. Once the updated `action` attribute is set, you can trigger submit method programatically.

```
const form = document.getElementById("form_id");

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); // <- HERE you stop the exection before some processings

  let action = "index.html";

  if (/* some condition */) {
    action = "index_admin.html";
  }

  form.setAttribute("action", action);
  form.submit();
});
```

Although, I would suggest not to use direct password/login conditions checks inside your code, since it can be inspected from the browser and people can use this to hack credentials of admin somehow.

Comment: what is (e) used for sir?